# Is there a way to `apply` a function to one column of a dataframe while leaving the other columns fixed?

Tags: python, pandas

Basically I'm wondering if there's a more "Pandathonic" way of expressing this:

```
df.apply(lambda col: myfunc(col) if col == "mycol" else col)
```

Something like

```
df.apply(myfunc, subset = ["mycol"])
```

is the kind of thing I have in mind.

The reason is that I'm trying avoid doing this:

```
df['mycol']=myfunc(df['mycol'])
```

as I'm on a functional programming kick at the moment and I want my code to eschew side-effects.

Comment: `df['mycol'].apply(lambda x: myfunc(x))`?

Comment: no i want to have the whole dataframe returned

Comment: If `apply` is not done `inplace` you still have to make an assignment, so what is the difference?

Comment: @helpanderrr i'm basically looking for a "forward pipe" for functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pandas 0.16 or later, you can use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#dataframe-assign), which returns a new DataFrame with whatever assignments you tell it to do, but doesn't modify the original:

```
>>> d = pandas.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [8, 88, 888]})
>>> d
   A    B
0  1    8
1  2   88
2  3  888
>>> d.assign(A=d.A**2)
   A    B
0  1    8
1  4   88
2  9  888
>>> d
   A    B
0  1    8
1  2   88
2  3  888
```

Comment: this is interesting (didn't know about this method) although it will get awkward quickly with pipelining together multiple functions

Comment: @maxymoo odd that you say it will get awkward; the point is chaining is quite intuitive and natural (as opposed to in-place type operations)

Comment: @Jeff my point is that if I want to compose functions `f1`, `f2` and `f3`, the syntax would be `d.assign(A=f3(d.assign(A=f2(d.assign(A=f1))))`; agree that this is better than in-place, but I would argue that this is less readable than a "forward pipe" style syntax using something like `apply`

Comment: oh sorry just realised you're meant to chain together the assigns like this `d.assign(A=f1(d.A)).assign(A=f2(d.A)).assign(A=f3(d.A)))`; this is actually exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: actually you can't do that, it should be `d.assign(A = lambda x: f1(x.A)).assign(A = lambda x: f2(x.A)).assign(A = lambda x: f3(x.A))`

Comment: you can also use ``.pipe`` for this (in fact thats exactly what you should use), e.g. ``df.A.pipe(f1).pipe(f2).pipe(f3)``